# +CMS ERROR: 350 when sending SMS in Quectel EC20

Tags: sms, gprs, quectel

Testing Quectel EC20 GPRS module.  Basic AT commands worked, HTTP worked but when testing SMS, after sending AT+CMGS="MOB NUMBER", returns with +CMS ERROR: 350.  What is the cause of this error?

Comment: same problem here with Quectel EG25-G... could it be carrier compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because of network failure. change the SIM or try with new port